# Kubernetes - minikube service connection timeout

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have a Docker environment with 3 containers: nginx, PHP with Laravel and a MySQL database.  It works fine, and I'm now trying to learn Kubernetes.

I was hoping to create a deployment and a service just for the nginx container to make it simple to start with:

Here is the deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: toolkit-app-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            container: toolkit-server
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                container: toolkit-server
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: toolkit-server
                  image: my/toolkit-server:test
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 8000
            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: my-cred
```

Here is the service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: backend
spec:
    selector:
        container: toolkit-server
    ports:
        - protocol: "TCP"
          port: 80
          targetPort: 8000
    type: LoadBalancer
```

And just incase it's needed, here is the nginx part of the docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    server:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/nginx.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        container_name: toolkit-server
```

The deployment is created successfully and I can see that 1/1 pods are running.

However when I run `minikube service backend`, the URL I get just times out.

I was expecting to see some sort of nginx page, maybe an nginx error - but with a time out I'm not sure what the next step is.

I'm brand new to Kubernetes to theres a good chance I've messed the ports up or something basic.  Any help appreciated.

Edit:

As advised by @david-maze I changed the following in the deployment.yaml:

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 80
```

And the following in service.yaml:

```
targetPort: 80
```

This gave me an nginx error page when viewed in the browser, as expected, but crucially no longer times out.

Comment: Have you made any change to your Nginx configuration so that it's listening on port 8000, or is the process inside the container listening on the default HTTP port 80?  I might change the two mentions of port 8000 in the pod and service specs to port 80.

Comment: Hi, my original Docker environment was accessed through localhost:8000 - I've changed the deployment and service yamls both to port 80 and I now get a 502 bad gateway nginx  error - which is progress! Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Lee. Could you edit your question with thew info mentioned above? It would make it easier to analyze.

Comment: No problem - I've edited the question

Comment: Thanks @Lee. So what is the actual question now? Is the current behavior (after the changes proposed by David) the one you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Kind of! I'm still trying to wrap my head round how to get my Docker setup (3 containers nginx, php, mysql) working through Kubernetes - 3 pods (nginx, php, mysql).  I have no idea how to fix the 502 error but at least I can see it rather than the whole thing just timing out.  Davids solution got me 1 step closer to what I'm after.

Comment: Hi again @Lee. I think it would be best to close this topic and ask another question with only the info needed to resolve the 502 error you have right now. Issue from the title `Kubernetes - minikube service connection timeout` is no longer valid here so it would be better to do so for the clarity sake. I will compose a community wiki answer in a moment based on what was done here already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As discussed in the comments the issue was due to wrong port configuration.

**TargetPort** is the port on which the service will send requests to, that your pod will be listening on. Your application in the container will need to be listening on this port also.

**ContainerPort** defines the port on which app can be reached out inside the container.

So in your use case the deployment should have:

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 80
```

and the service:

```
targetPort: 80
```

This will make the connection not to timeout anymore.